# How to change div image for a div when user clicks on an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div image in css and another small image. If I click on small image, I would like my div image to change.

How to write a script for this ?

Comment: Show your CSS, HTML, code. Something!

Answer (score 0):

```
var div=document.getElementById('yourDiv');
var height = div.style.height;
var width = div.style.width;
var enlargedHeight = height + *size to increase goes here*;
var enlargedWidth = width + *size to increase goes here*;

function grow() {
if (div) {
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(newimage.gif)';
height=enlargedHeight; 
width=enlargedWidth;
}
}
```

and your div

```
<div id="yourDiv" onclick="grow();">
/*content*/
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just write an onclick handler like:

```
document.getElementById ('theSmallImageId').onclick = function{
document.getElementById ('TheDivId').style.backgroundImage = urlToTheNewImage; 
};
```

I hope this is helpful.